# Strange characters appearing in bash variable expansion

Tags: bash, macos, shell, curl, command-line

Trying to do the following on contos7 works as I expect:

```
pod_in_question=$(curl -u uname:password -k very.cluster.com/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/ | grep -i '"name": "myapp-' | cut -d '"' -f 4)

echo "$pod_in_question"

curl -u uname:password -k -X DELETE "very.cluster.com/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/${pod_in_question}"
```

However, trying the same thing on MacOS (10.12.1) yields:

> curl: (3) [globbing] bad range in column 92

When I try to *curl* the last line with a `-g` option it substitutes with a malformed name such as: `myapp-\\x1b[m\\x1b[Kl1eti\`

The echo statement would always execute just fine and show something like `myapp-v7454` which I later want to put into the last curl statement.  So where are these other characters coming from?

Comment: It would be nice to have a bit more information, since none of your example is repeatable.  What value do you get for `pod_in_question` on Mac?  Perhaps there is a character encoding issue.  If so, you could translate it through _iconv_.  But the substitution you showed at the last part looks like one of your calls injected [ANSI escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php).  It's possible that _grep_ isn't detecting non-TTY output and is colorizing.  Try adding `--color=never` argument to _grep_.

Comment: @paddy updated with more info

Comment: You need to debug your chain of calls.  Those escape sequences set the screen mode and erase the line.  Outputting that with `echo` to a terminal that supports escape sequences would have the _appearance_ of being fine.  Instead, why don't you examine your value with `echo "$pod_in_question" | hexdump -C`.

Comment: I agree with paddy - a hexdump would be very informative. Other useful output could be generated by `printf '%q\n' "$pod_in_question"` instead of the `echo`.

Comment: @paddy, you were right all along. Hexdump reveled ```myapp-\E[m\E[K08wsz``` which was coming form the grep's coloration. Adding the suggested option have removed the unwanted escape characters. Please, made your comment an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The substitution you showed at the last part looks like one of your calls injected [ANSI escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php).  It's possible that *grep* isn't detecting non-TTY output and is colorizing.

On a terminal that supports ANSI escape sequences, your particular codes might not be visible.  The codes `^E[m^E[K` set the screen mode and clear the current line.  That's why you thought the `echo` command proved your data was correct.

You can examine the raw data with:

```
echo "$pod_in_question" | hexdump -C
```

And you should see there are other characters in there which did not appear in your terminal before.  When you put these "invisible" codes into the URL, *curl* tries to encode them and then fails when it encounters a control character (ESC).

The solution is to add the argument `--color=never` to your *grep* call, which will disable colorization.

Answer (score 3):

### A robust solution - Basic `cURL` CLI debugging.

This answer is revised after it's been identified that the issue for the OP relates to curl applying color output.

There's a proposed answer which explains clearly what the embedded special characters meant, and instructions to override the `grep` behaviour to not output color.  Certainly this is a good practise for `grep` use in piping.  There are however a number of best practises that can help diagnose this or a similar issue with `cURL` and ultimately lead to the most robust solution.

**Re-creating the problem**

1. Assuming it's a JSON Content-Type, we use `echo {'"name": "myapp-7414"'}` to simulate the output from `cURL`
2. We filter the text and set a variable with it that we use in a `cURL` command
3. We force `grep` to output color, since it doesn't normally by default when outputting to a tty.

   **Recreation:**

   ```
   myvar=$(echo {'"name": "myapp-7414"'} | grep --color=always -i '"name": "myapp-' | cut -d '"' -f 4)
   curl "https://www.google.com/${myvar}"
   ```

   **Output:**

   > ```
   > curl: (3) [globbing] bad range in column 32
   > ```

**First up:**
`'{}'` are special characters to `cURL`, period.

- **The best practise for URL syntax in `cURL`:**

  - If Variable Expansion is required:

    - Apply the `-g` switch to disable potential globbing done by `cURL`
  - **Otherwise:**

    - Use `$variable` as part of a "quoted" url string, instead of `${variable}`

**Second:** In addition to `-g`, we add `--libcurl /tmp/libcurl` so we can get some insight into what `cURL` is seeing.

**Recreation with `-g` and `--libcurl`:**

- ```
  curl -g --libcurl /tmp/libcurl  "https://www.google.com/${myvar}"
  ```

  **Output:**

  > `<p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request <ins>That’s all we know.`

**Perfect**, at least now everything is getting to the server and back!  Let's see what `cURL` sent out to the server:

```
cat /tmp/libcurl
```

**Surely enough we find this line:**  (note the bold part).

> ```
> curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/myapp-\033[m7414");
> ```

So we know that:

1. The **shell** is doing something strange with our variable.
2. `cURL` knows not to try glob once we send the `-g` switch.  That way - If there **is** an error with the shell variable, we can actually **see** what it is.  We shouldn't be debugging a globbing error if we're not trying to use URL Ranges.
3. The special characters are colors.  They represent the `--color=always` that we added to simulate the OPs environment.

At this point.  Since it looks like we're working with JSON data, why not just use a widely available, high performance JSON parsing tool.  That has a number of benefits, including:

- Not relying on any environment that could affect string filtering
- Can **request** the data we want (aka. "name")
- The app name "myapp" can change and we won't have to re-write the code to retrieve it.
- It's cleaner and accounts for things I haven't considered yet.

If we used `jq` for example (while we're at it, we don't need the `-g` switch because we don't need '{}' for the variable because we're already double `"` the URL):

```
myvar=$(echo {'"name": "myapp-7414"'} | jq -r .name)
curl --libcurl /tmp/libcurl "https://www.google.com/$myvar"
```

**Now we get:**

> <p>The requested URL `/myapp-7414` **was not found on this server.**  That’s all we know.

**Great.**  It's all working now.  It should be obvious that the test URL here being `www.google.com` is obviously not going to know was `myapp-7414` was.

So we've gone from :

- Globbing bad range, to:
- Malformed URL, to:
- URL not found on server.

We **could** also as suggested elsewhere change the `grep` output and override it to `--color=never` (As I have noted: If `grep` has to be used, the `--color=never` is a great way to use it as a best practise when piping strings, period.).  However, given the portability issues already experienced because of string filtering, and the fact that we are already handed structured data on a plate that can be parsed reliably, the more robust solution would be to do just that, if possible.

Comment: Ok I see your point now. If I could accept two answers I would since  you put a ton of effort. Still having a third-party ```jq``` tool for portability is something that I would steer clear of. It terminates the point of simplicity within a shell script. If it comes to writing a script that requires extra dependencies it is time to use something heavier. Essentially basic tools "must work no matter what" or I need to learn how to make them work in such situations. Otherwise, their value diminishes significantly.

Comment: @user3081519 yeah - totally valid, and i agree, I much prefer portable (like ... will it run on my openwrt router with `busybox` portable).  Also depends on application and implementation to an extent.  My answer is there for those that land on it from search results giving them a process to follow that might help a number of scenarios.  Cheers for the comments.